# Converting data from imperial (fl oz) to metric (mL) and back again

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, data-conversion

Storing everything in database as imperial (fl. oz) and then converting to metric (mL) if the user has selected that as their preferred measurement system.

The calculation is done on the fly and updated on the UI.

My problem is that because I'm storing the data as oz. if a user is using ml. to add to their total then when total amount shown is significantly less. E.g. 500mL is converted to 16oz then converted back to mL as 473mL.

Here are my conversion formulas:
_toMetric is used when the value is coming from the database as fl. oz and _toImperial is used to convert the users entered amount to oz. before storing the database.

```
  double _toMetric(int value) {
    return (value * 29.574);
  }

  double _toImperial(int value) {
    return (value / 29.574);
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you're inserting an int instead of a double.

500ml = 16.9oz

you are inserting in your function 16oz which is equal to 473.

the number should be a double not an integer.